# how to inject a httprequestmessage / endpoint

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, controller, httprequest

I have a controller in my REST API, where I do a HttpRequestMessage. The way I am doing it right now is by using the IConfiguration interface to fetch the endpoint as a variable:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
public MyController(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient){
_configuration = configuration;
_httpClient = httpClient;
}
...
...
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
...
...
var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _configuration["MY_ENDPOINT"]);
await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
...
...
return Ok();
}
```

The thing is, that it is apparently better to have the api endpoint injected via an interface and I honestly don't know what or how that is done.

I do inject the HttpClient and the IConfiguration, but that's something I've done several times and seen others do. But just injecting an endpoint (without IConfiguration), seems unfamiliar for me. The ... is just because I've taken out code that doesn't have influence on the question.

Is there any simple way to just inject the endpoint - and is it just me that don't understand the reason for it?

I guess I have to create an interface and in that some logic that just returns the endpoint? But isn't that just double work?

**MY SOLUTION:**

the only workaround I can think of at the moment is just by injecting a string:

```
private readonly string _myEndpoint;
```

and then inject it:

```
_myEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_ENDPOINT");
```

and finally use that in my httpRequestMessage:

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _myEndpoint);
```

That's not an interface, but again I don't use the IConfiguration-interface and don't write a lot of unneeded code.

If any better / smarter suggestion, then please shout out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way that you can load "options" into the service collection via:

```
services.Configure<EndpointConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("EndPointConfig"));
```

The `EndpointConfig` here is a class that you would have to define:

```
public class EndpointConfig 
{
    public string EndpointUrl {get;set;}
}
```

In this particular example the `appsettings.json` "EndPointConfig" would need a EndpointUrl, here's a rough example:

```
{
    "EndPointConfig" : {
        "EndpointUrl" : "https://localhost"
    }

}
```

then when you get to your controller you pass in the config like so:

```
private readonly EndpointConfig _configuration;
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public MyController(IOptions<EndpointConfig> configuration, HttpClient httpClient){
    _configuration = configuration.Value;
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

There is some good documentation around this if you would like to try it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1

---

If you don't want to define a `EndpointConfig` section in your appsettings.json as your describing in the comments then you would simply configue i with the Configuration object:

```
services.Configure<EndpointConfig>(Configuration);
```

Now it will search for the property name (in this case `EndpointUrl`) in the base object of your appsettings json:

```
{
   "EndpointUrl" : "https://localhost"
}
```

If you want to look for a different name i.e. `My_Endpoint` you would have to simply rename your property:

```
public class EndpointConfig 
{
    public string My_Endpoint {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This seems very much like the path I want to go. The only thing is, that MY_ENDPOINT already is a known variable and that's the one I have to use. Can I still use this approach, but reach MY_ENDPOINT instead? Because loading it into the service collection and creating a seperate config class is definetly what I was searching for, but how to create a class that fetches a object from the appsettings.json, that is already there, I don't know. Instead of the appsettings.json having an endpointconfig, could I somehow fetch the MY_ENDPOINT that is already created and use your setup?

Comment: Where is MY_ENDPOINT defined? If it's in the appsettings, then yes, you would simply do `services.Configure<EndpointConfig>(Configuration);` and it would search for `EndpointUrl` (taken from my example) in your appsettings, if you want EndpointUrl  to be something else you would simply rename the property on the class

Comment: it's defined inside appsettings.json and looks like this { "MY_ENDPOINT": "https://this-endpoint.com", "MY_ENDPOINT2": "https://this-endpoint2.com", "MY_ENDPOINT3": "https://this-endpoint3.com" }  and I am only interested in fetching MY_ENDPOINT. The way you've put it up - with EndPointConfig having a string called EndPointUrl, I can see that I would call the string My_endpoint - but when there are no objects above MY_ENDPOINT in the appsettings.json, wouldn't it be searching for a "EndpointConfig" that isn't there? Sorry for not understanding this part clearly.

Comment: It depends on how you configure it in the DI, in my answer I described having a `EndpointConfig` section but if you don't want to have that section you can simply do `services.Configure<EndpointConfig>(Configuration);` as I mentioned before and it will search your appsettings for the property names and not need the `EndpointConfig` section :)